# CSS3 PIE pushes sticky footer off screen in IE7

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer, css3pie

I'm using [this sticky footer layout](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/html-code.html) along with [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1287) and in IE compatibility mode it's causing the footer to split where the content of my footer is shown below the screen and the CSS3 Pie styles/background/etc are in the correct spot where the sticky footer goes.

How to get them to play nicely together?

Open this jsfiddle in IE and then hit the compatibility button at the top (left of reload button in IE9). If button is not visible, just go to the following in the menu: "Tools-->Compatibility View".
http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/srwtC/2/

**UPDATE:**
Use this fiddle example instead as the one above is not an accurate representation of the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/8rZWu/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2):

Changing the positioning of the footer seems to work for me:

```
#footer
{
    position: absolute; /* This is the important bit */
    margin-top: -81px; /* negative value of footer height */
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    height: 80px;
    width: 75%;
    clear:both;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 48pt;
    font-weight: bold;

    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat #EBEBEB; /*non-CSS3 browsers will use this*/
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#EEFF99) to(#66EE33)); /*old webkit*/
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33); /*new webkit*/
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33); /*gecko*/
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33); /*IE10 preview*/
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33); /*opera 11.10+*/
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33); /*future CSS3 browsers*/
    -pie-background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33); /*PIE*/

    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid black;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;

    behavior: url('/js/lib/PIE-1.0.0/PIE.htc');

}
```

See Here:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/srwtC/3/show/

**UPDATE**

```
#footer {
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-width: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0; /*IMPORTANT*/
    right: 0; /*IMPORTANT*/
    margin: -51px auto 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0;
    background: #E1DAC6;
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat #EBEBEB;
    -pie-background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    behavior: url('/js/lib/PIE-1.0.0/PIE.htc');
}
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that works with this example. However, I may have oversimplified it as the footer on my actual page now has other problems. I found the original template I'm working off of, added PIE styling to it's footer, and repro'd the problem with your solution.

Comment: Okay, [here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/8rZWu/embedded/result/) with your solution and the actual template I'm using. The footer loses it's alignment with the columns above.
 
http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/8rZWu/embedded/result/

Comment: Didn't work. I updated the #footer section on the example two comments up (http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/8rZWu/embedded/result/) and the footer is still left aligned.

Comment: NOTE: Specifically, it didn't work in IE9 and IE compatibility mode.